# Can I load multiple QTranslator files, each for different parts of my application?

Tags: qt, qtranslate

I can install translator as `myApp.installTranslator(&translator)`

Is it possible to have multiple translation files and load them from different parts of my application? How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. As doc said:

> Adds the translation file translationFile to the list of translation
>   files to be used for translations.
>
> Multiple translation files can be installed. Translations are searched
>   for in the reverse order in which they were installed, so the most
>   recently installed translation file is searched first and the first
>   translation file installed is searched last. The search stops as soon
>   as a translation containing a matching string is found.
>
> Installing or removing a QTranslator, or changing an installed
>   QTranslator generates a LanguageChange event for the QCoreApplication
>   instance. A QApplication instance will propagate the event to all
>   toplevel windows, where a reimplementation of changeEvent can
>   re-translate the user interface by passing user-visible strings via
>   the tr() function to the respective property setters. User-interface
>   classes generated by Qt Designer provide a retranslateUi() function
>   that can be called.
>
> The function returns true on success and false on failure.

You need to load some translation file, `qApp` macro to get instance of `QApplication` outside `main()` function and do something like:

```
QTranslator translator;//somewhere

void MainWindow::on_someButton_clicked()
{
    translator.load("://en.qm");
    qApp->installTranslator( &translator );
    ui->retranslateUi(this);               //for Qt designer
}
```

Also you can remove translator with:

```
void MainWindow::on_someButton_2_clicked()
{
    qApp->removeTranslator(&translator);
    ui->retranslateUi(this);
}
```

Internationalization is a big part, so I can suggest also next links:

[Internationalization with Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html)

[Writing Source Code for Translation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/i18n-source-translation.html)

And books:

[Foundations of Qt Development (Expert's Voice in Open Source)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598318)  **Chapter 10**

[C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 (2nd Edition) (Prentice Hall Open Source Software Development Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) **Chapter 18**

[Qt4.8. Professionalnoe programmirovanie na C++ (Russian)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/5977507364) **Chapter 31** (for russian-speakers)

Comment: Can I use this for a webserver, where each client connection could have a different language? In my case every session is a QObject and I am using tr().